# How to configure Bonobo git for a private repository over internet

Tags: git, server, bonobo

Can anyone provide me with a solution to make my own laptop-server(not a real server per se) with Bonobo Git server over the internet? I have successfully set up a Bonobo Git Server on local LAN with IIS, and I want to share my repositories no matter where I am. I am aware that I need to forward ports on my router to let myself access to this server, however, I do not know which ones (maybe 80,443 and 22 for HTTP, HTTPS and ssh).

Comment: Hint: ssh — port 22.

Comment: Thanks haha, a missclick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made it. It was possible using NoIP to assign a free domain to my pc, instead of using the IP, this step is optional but recommended.
Once done that and the server is up with the IIS, the only thing to do is to open ports. If you will use HTTP then open the port 80 in your router.
However, if it is HTTPS you must install the certificate with IIS and then open the port 443.

Comment: What about SSH?